# How do i take a mongoose model out of an array that is within another mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Okay so i have 2 schemas from mongoose, a `model` schema and a `diagram` schema.

*Model.ts*

```
import mongoose, {Schema} from 'mongoose';
import { Diagram} from "./index";

const modelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    name: String,
    diagram: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Diagram'}]
})

const Model = mongoose.model('Model', modelSchema);
export default Model
```

*Diagram.ts*

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const diagramSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    info: String,
    version: Number,
    diagram: String
})

const Diagram = mongoose.model('Diagram', diagramSchema)
export default Diagram
```

As seen in my `Model.ts`, my model uses an array made from `diagrams` and i want to be able to find my schema diagram within that array. But i don't know how. I've already tried to find the diagram using `Model.findOne()` but that needs the ID of the schema whereas i want to search for it using the diagram name. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trying, searching and pulling my hair out i managed to find a solution which was surprisingly a lot easier than i thought.

```
const diagram = await Model.find({name:modelname}).populate({
    path: 'diagram',
    match: {name: diagramname}
});
```